Ultralytics YOLOv8 throwing no labels found error when trying to train
I was trying to use Ultralytics' YOLOv8 model for instance segmentation on a custom dataset. While running the training, it throws an error that says all labels were empty in label.cache and thus cannot start training. I understand that it's probably caused by the labels not getting detected properly.
This is the error:
ValueError: All labels empty in F:\Miscellaneous Datasets\DACL10K_v2\dacl10k_v2_devphase\datasets\dacl10k\train\labels.cache, 
can not start training without labels. See 
https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/wiki/Train-Custom-Data

I'm using the following lines to train the model:
model = YOLO("yolov8n-seg.pt")
results = model.train(
    batch=8,
    device="cpu",
    data="./data.yaml",
    epochs=7
)

The directory structure of my work is like this:
root
|
|--datasets
|   |
|   |--dacl10k
|      |
|      |--test
|      |     |--images
|      |          |--<test images>
|      |--train
|      |     |
|      |     |--images
|      |     |    |--<train images>
|      |     |
|      |     |--labels
|      |          |--<train labels>
|      |       
|      |--val
|         |
|         |--images
|         |     |--<validation images>
|         |
|         |--labels
|               |--<validation labels>
|
|--data.yaml
|
|--yolo_train.ipynb

I'm running the script in yolo_train.ipynb. Now, I made sure that the label names are the same as the file names of the training images, the only difference being the file type extension (.jpg for images, .txt for labels). Each image gets a .txt file with the same name. Each row in the txt file corresponds to an object in the image, in the following format:
<class index> <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> .... <x> <y>,
where the class index specifies the class and the x, and y values denote the polygon's vertices marking the object to be detected.
My data.yaml file looks something like this:
# Train/val/test sets 
path: F:/Miscellaneous Datasets/DACL10K_v2/dacl10k_v2_devphase/datasets/dacl10k  # dataset root dir
train: F:/Miscellaneous Datasets/DACL10K_v2/dacl10k_v2_devphase/datasets/dacl10k/train/images
val: F:/Miscellaneous Datasets/DACL10K_v2/dacl10k_v2_devphase/datasets/dacl10k/val/images
test: F:/Miscellaneous Datasets/DACL10K_v2/dacl10k_v2_devphase/datasets/dacl10k/test/images

# Directories
train_label_dir: F:/Miscellaneous Datasets/DACL10K_v2/dacl10k_v2_devphase/datasets/dacl10k/train/labels
val_label_dir: F:/Miscellaneous Datasets/DACL10K_v2/dacl10k_v2_devphase/datasets/dacl10k/val/trains

# Classes (19)
nc: 19  # number of classes
names: ['Graffiti',' Drainage', 'Wetspot', 'Weathering', 'Crack', 'Rockpocket', 'Spalling', 'WConccor', 'Cavity', 'Efflorescence', 'Rust', 'PEquipment', 'ExposedRebars', 'Bearing', 'Hollowareas', 'JTape', 'Restformwork', 'ACrack', 'EJoint']
# class names

I previously tried using relative file paths instead of absolute, but I didn't have any luck.

I seem to have found the answer - the labels were not being recognized because they weren't normalized. YOLO requires the xy-coordinates to be normalized between 0 and 1.
Now I just need to figure out how that's done :/

Instead of answering your own question with an unclear answer and not a full solution, add the new information as a comment or edit your answer.

I apologize, I am still pretty new to asking questions here. I will do as recommended.
